# TF2 Binds. I'm not so sure if I should use autoexec.cfg

Tags: team-fortress-2

How can I make my settings that i put into the console stay every time I load TF2? I want to put cl_showfps 0 and mat_phong 0 . Every time I put them in and exit TF2 these settings reset. I would also like to know how to revert these changes in case everything goes bad.

Answer (score 3):

Open up autoexec.cfg in a text editor, and add those two lines you wanted in there. This will make sure that when you open up the game, the autoexec will run, running those commands:

> cl_showfps 0; mat_phong 0;

That said, if you want to revert those changes, an easy way would be to bind a key to turn those commands off. So you can also add in your config a bind like the following:

> bind  "cl_showfps 1; mat_phong 1";

Or whatever your default mat_phong setting is. This way, even if your autoexec starts up and you don't like the changes, you can press that key to reset it to normal. Then if you don't want those settings, simply remove them from your autoexec.cfg

Comment: I don't quite understand the first part of opening up a text editor. Is it the console or do I just put it on pad? And if it is pad, then where do i put it?

Comment: So if you open up "autoexec.cfg" using the Notepad, you will see nothing initially, this is the way things are, it's customizable. So you can go ahead and add what I edited above in there.

Comment: Where is the auto.exec.cfg file located?